# How do I work out reduction percentage for a group of drenches?

Tags: r, reduction

[image]
I have data from a sheep producer who has tried several different drenches (treatment used for worm control) on his flock of sheep in order to work out the individual efficacy of each drug. The producer took faecal samples at Day 0 which represented the number of eggs in each animal before treatment and Day 14 samples which represented the number of eggs after treatment. The Column `EPG` means Eggs Per Gram of faeces and these values are what I need to use when determining the reduction percentage (i.e. compare post treatments with the pre-control and control groups). From the image, I need to get a reduction percentage from `BZ` and `LEV` (post counts) using the PRE data (pre-counts)

I have tried the following:

```
model <- fecr_stan(data1$before, data1$after, rawCounts=FALSE, preCF=50, 
                      paired=TRUE, indEfficacy=TRUE)
```

But I get error message:

> Error in if (mean(preFEC) < mean(postFEC)) warning("mean of
>   pre-treatment is smaller of post-treatment. Results may be unreliable
>   if default priors are used.\n") :    missing value where TRUE/FALSE
>   needed

Comment: Your error message suggests some clues about the error e.g. missing values.  But, as there is no data example to test, it is difficult to check the issue

Comment: Interesting question but need more info. Per R tag (hover to see): Use `dput()` for data and specify all non-base packages with `library()` calls.